# COM object with additional interface: client can't see the interface

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007

I have a following COM object:

```
unit Unit4;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, ComObj, Project1_TLB, StdVcl;

const
  IID_IMyTestIntf: TGUID = '{D22502A1-B76C-4E1E-A77C-558B8A6450C1}';

type
  IMyTestIntf = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{D22502A1-B76C-4E1E-A77C-558B8A6450C1}']
  end;

  TMyTestObj = class(TTypedComObject, IMyTestObj, IMyTestIntf)
  private
  protected
  public

  end;

var
  UsedIntf: IMyTestObj;

implementation

uses ComServ;

initialization
  TTypedComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyTestObj, Class_MyTestObj,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

An this is the type library:

```
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  Project1MajorVersion = 1;
  Project1MinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_Project1: TGUID = '{70CAFFB4-B90D-42EF-9673-F81DB403B9BF}';

  IID_IMyTestObj: TGUID = '{26F41FF7-9C49-45D8-86BC-C38AB302B9E6}';
  CLASS_MyTestObj: TGUID = '{6F6E4B1D-100D-4DC5-A9EB-10C90BF422AB}';
type
  IMyTestObj = interface;

  MyTestObj = IMyTestObj;


  IMyTestObj = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{26F41FF7-9C49-45D8-86BC-C38AB302B9E6}']
  end;

  CoMyTestObj = class
    class function Create: IMyTestObj;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IMyTestObj;
  end;

implementation

uses ComObj;

class function CoMyTestObj.Create: IMyTestObj;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_MyTestObj) as IMyTestObj;
end;

class function CoMyTestObj.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IMyTestObj;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_MyTestObj) as IMyTestObj;
end;

end.
```

When I try to get the *IMyTestInterface* the *QueryInterface* returns E_NOINTERFACE:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  o: IMyTestObj;
  i: IMyTestIntf;
  r: HRESULT;
begin
  o := CreateComObject(CLASS_MyTestObj) as IMyTestObj;
  r := o.QueryInterface(IID_IMyTestIntf, i); //returns E_NOINTERFACE
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(r));
end;
```

But if I put *IMyTestInterface* into type library everything works as expected.

Since *IMyTestInterface* will be used in more than one module, I don' want to add it to the type library every time.

I did some debugging and found that *QueryInterface* actually makes two calls to the objects *QueryInterface*: one with *IID_IMyTestIntf* which returns S_OK and another with GUID {AF86E2E0-B12D-4C6A-9C5A-D7AA65101E90} which would be *IInspectable*, and this one returns E_NOINTERFACE.

Is there a simple solution to implement additional interface into a COM object without putting it into type library?

Comment: The simplest solution is to declaratively (in the type library) mark your component as the implementor of the interface. So the interface itself does need to be in a type library. If you have multiple COM components implementing that interface put it into its own separate type library and add a reference to it to your other type libraries.

Comment: Can't mark it as implementor since typelib does not know about this interface (it is not offered in the selection list) - it works only if its in the typelib itself or in the uses list. If I save it in the separate library and add it to uses list then I must register that type library on every machine that uses it. This is too much hassle an it would be visible throughout the system - but it needs to be used only internally. It would be easier to solve this through code.

Comment: Actually I've just tried it and it works in D2007 with no extra work required. Have you rebuilt both projects (server and client)?

Comment: Tried it now in Tokyo. All rebuilt. Same thing. Are you sure you don't have IMyTestIntf in the typelib?

Comment: Ahhhh! Forgot to mention: COM object is in exe, not dll. Tried it now with DLL and it works. But I need this in an exe server.